# Why does the default argument not work in a template function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, standards, overload-resolution

```
struct A {};

template<typename T>
void f(int n, T m = 3.14159)
{}

int main()
{    
    f(8, A{}); // ok
    f(8); // error: no matching function for call to 'f'
}
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PrKfYvaaE)

**Why does the default argument not work in a template function?**

---

**EDIT:** I also tried following, and wonder why it didn't work as well.

```
void g(int, auto = 3.14159)
{}
```

Comment: How should it resolve the type of the template parameter `T` in the second call?

Comment: I think `T` should be `double` in the second case.

Comment: Try defaulting the type of the template parameter to `double` as well.

Comment: Please don't change your question after receiving an answer.

Comment: You completely changed the question with that last edit....

Comment: I rolled your question back so that the answers make sense.  If you have a new question, ask a new question please.

Comment: Edited your question a bit to reduce code duplication. Feel free to roll back if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default function arguments don't affect template argument deduction.

You need a default argument for the template parameter too: `typename T = double`.

---

As for `void g(int, auto = 3.14159)`, there seems to be no way to fix it.

Comment: How about `auto` form rather than `template` form? See the updated code.

Comment: @xmllmx That doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: The `auto` version is essentially an equivalent to the template version with the same problems but no corresponding solution because you cannot specify a default type for the `auto`.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you gave a value for the second function parameter at the call site, which the compiler could use to deduce the type of the second template argument, which then let it determine which version of the template to instantiate and call.

In the second case, you gave the compiler no information about the type for the second template argument, so it cannot use the template to instantiate the function, and so there is no function with that signature available to call.

The compiler will not use a parameter's default value to deduce a template argument type for that parameter (keep in mind that potentially many choices for the type `T` could accept a `double` as a default value).